# How to send chat request (subscribe) to number on Openfire server using XMPP framework (iphone) and populate the roster?

Tags: iphone, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I am letting people register to my App using their mobile numbers. I can see the people online on the admin panel. But unless I manually go and add them to the roster and subscribe, they can't chat with each other. How can I do this without having to manually add them?

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure [Openfire's Subscription Plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp).

From the [Readme of the Plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/subscription/readme.html):

> This plugin can be configuured to automatically accept or reject
>   subscription requests. When set to accept subscription requests users
>   will be able to add someone to their roster (aka "Buddy List" or
>   "Contacts") without having to wait for a manual subscription
>   acceptance from the requested user.

Comment: That's a piece of the problem but I think OP wants to automatically populate the roster rather than generating subscribe requests for each.

Comment: Thanks for update. But I have tried installing that plugin as well. The roster ain't getting populated. And I want the users in the roster list with subscription as '*both*'.

Answer (score 0):

To send friend request :

```
 XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"Buddyname"];
 [xmppRoster addUser:newBuddy withNickname:nil];
```

Accept Request:

```
 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence{

    if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"subscribe"]) {

        [xmppRoster acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:presence.from andAddToRoster:YES];
    }
```